# jQuery replace removes line breaks in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have the code:

```
$("#txtDescription").blur(function(){
    $("#txtDescription").text($("#txtDescription").text().replace('@', ''));
})
```

which removes the @ symbol is someone copies it into a text area. The problem with this is that in IE (all versions) it also removes any line breaks which were added and adds all text on a single line with spaces. The other problem is that if I save the information to a DB table the line breaks are actually there so it only seems to be a visual thing. Not good if a user thinks their information is all on a single line.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to remove characters if a user pastes into a textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#txtDescription").blur(function(){
    $(this).val(function(i,val){
        return val.replace('@', '')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if `#txtDescription` is a `<textarea>` as your post suggests, then you want to use jQuery's `val` function instead of `text`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#txtDescription").blur(function(){
    var newval = $(this).val().replace('@','');
    $(this).val(newval);
})
```